# Can we have a Non-Gaussian Likelihood and which are the conditions or examples?

Tags: gauss-law, probability, randomness, non-gaussianity

I am working on Fisher formalism and MCMC method. It seems that Fisher formalisme assumes that posterior is always Gaussian. So if I find with MCMC a gaussian posterior, I validate the results of Fisher computation (by getting a Gaussian distribution for both).

Now, I would like to know if the Gaussianity for Likelihood is always guaranteed, independently from the PDF I use.

More concretly, if I have the likelihood with a PDF $f(x)$ :

$$\mathcal{L} = \big(\prod_{k}\,f(x_{k})\big)\quad(1)$$

**1) Under which conditions we have the Gaussianity ?**

Maybe, one has to take the $\log$ of $\mathcal{L}$ and then write :

$$\log\,\mathcal{L} = \sum_{k}\,\log\,f(x_{k})\quad(2)$$

So we could conclude that from "Central Limit Theorem", the sum on $k$ of "$\log f(x_{k})$" follows, with a near factor of $N$ values $x_{k}$, a Gaussian distribution. (Actually, I think the average of random variables following the same PDF has a Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution.

**Is it systematically the case for equation $(2)$ ? I mean, this is the $\log$ which implies the sum and then the gaussianity with the "Central Limit Theorem" ?**

So, this would be not the $\mathcal{L}$ which is gaussian (in equation $(1)$) but rather the $\log\,\mathcal{L}$ (in equation(2)).

From a rigorous point of view, I should write $f(x_k,\Theta)$ instead of $f(x_k)$ alone since $\Theta$ are the parameters of the model, shouldn't I ?

**3) And Finally, if the gaussianity of $\log\,\mathcal{L}$ (or $\mathcal{L}$, I don't know for instant) is not always guaranteed, could anyone give me an example or an illustration where there is no gaussianity.**

I hope to have been clear enough, feel free to ask me more precisions if need it.

Regards

ps: maybe this post should be moved to maths exchange forums or statistics forums.

Comment: This question is not about physics. It should be posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com, or https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Semoi : could you transfer it please to math.stackexchange.com ? Regards

Comment: There are two ways to move questions, 1) migration which is done by a moderator usually but not always after it is closed, and 2) DIY (do it yourself). General users can't move questions for you. In this case DIY is the solution. You click edit, then copy the text, and then paste it in a question post in the new site, then come back here and vote to close or delete it. It's important not to leave things cross-posted in multiple sites, one reason is that it leads to answer and comment fragmentation; a future reader finding one instance will miss the information at the other. *Thanks!*